# how to fix all Non-nullble warnings in my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I have the Asp.Net Core project with

```
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

I had added Identity and got 195+ warnings. How can I fix that without rewriting all the code by myself?

Comment: What are the warnings?

Comment: How do you fix it without fixing it? You don't. Go and fix them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Microsoft documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies
>
> Nullable reference types enable you to declare if variables of a
> reference type should or shouldn't be assigned a null value. The
> compiler's static analysis and warnings when your code might
> dereference null are the most important benefit of this feature. Once
> enabled, the compiler generates warnings that help you avoid throwing
> a System.NullReferenceException when your code runs.
>
> If your codebase is relatively small, you can turn on the feature in
> your project, address warnings, and enjoy the benefits of the improved
> diagnostics. Larger codebases may require a more structured approach
> to address warnings over time, enabling the feature for some as you
> address warnings in different types or files.

"Warnings" are generally a "Good Thing".

But if you're not prepared to update your code base, and/or you don't believe most of these warnings are valid (that's entirely possible), then you should probably remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project settings.

Please be sure to review all of these suggestions:

- [MSDN: Update a codebase with nullable reference types to improve null diagnostic warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies).